# NodeJS/Electron The given range isn't in document

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, electron

was programming on my electron program and I somehow got the error in my console:

> [10316:1101/170233.809:ERROR:CONSOLE(2564)] "The given range isn't in document.", source: chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/shell.js (2564)

I don't know what happened there, but I'd undo everything I did and I'm still getting this error. I can't see any messages in my window console (the chrome console from electron).

Answer (score 0):

Omg, I found the solution... I got the error, because I searched in the console for a specific word, and if I restart the application it's still in there... forgot about that, looks like the error tells me, that the word I searched for in the console can't be found... sorry guys